# How to trigger animation when routed to the same page with different URL parameter using Angular in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I was trying to to trigger the animation when the page is routed to itself with different url parameter.

For instance, for `post/1` url, the animation works fine but if I route to `post/2` or `post/3`, the animation does not work.

I wrote the animation using [Ionic Animation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/animations) and calling the method everytime the route parameter changes. Could anyone please help?

Here's an excerpt from my code

**HTML**

```
<ion-icon class="custom-icon" name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon>
```

**TS**

```
constructor(private animationController: AnimationController) {
  this.route.params.subscribe((val) => {
    this.animateIcon();
  });
}

animateIcon() {
  this.animationController
    .create()
    .addElement(document.querySelector('.custom-icon'))
    .duration(1500)
    .iterations(3)
    .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(0px)', 'translateX(-80px)')
    .fromTo('opacity', '1', '0')
    .play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself. Instead of capturing the class name using `querySelector`, I used `ElementRef` notation to make it work. Now it does work all the time when I route to any of the `/post` pages.

**HTML**

```
<ion-icon #leftIcon class="custom-icon" name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('icon1', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) leftIcon: ElementRef;

constructor(private animationController: AnimationController) {
  this.route.params.subscribe((val) => {
    this.animateIcon();
  });
}

animateIcon() {
  this.animationController
    .create()
    .addElement(this.leftIcon.nativeElement)
    .duration(1500)
    .iterations(3)
    .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(0px)', 'translateX(-80px)')
    .fromTo('opacity', '1', '0')
    .play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Put calling function to ionViewWillEnter()

```
constructor(private animationController: AnimationController) {

}

ionViewWillEnter(){
 this.route.params.subscribe((val) => {
    this.animateIcon();
  });
}

animateIcon() {
this.animationController
    .create()
    .addElement(document.querySelector('.custom-icon'))
    .duration(1500)
    .iterations(3)
    .fromTo('transform', 'translateX(0px)', 'translateX(-80px)')
    .fromTo('opacity', '1', '0')
    .play();
}
```